# Autosynthesized property 'delegate' will use synthesized instance variable '_delegate', not existing instance variable 'delegate' in MBProgressHUD.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and getting the following warning when trying to compile my objective C code:

```
MBProgressHUD.m:39:1: Autosynthesized property 'delegate' will use synthesized instance variable '_delegate', not existing instance variable 'delegate'
```

I am using MBProgressHUD from https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

```
Any help to fix this Warning?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the MBProgressHUD.h, try updating the code for property as mentioned below:

```
@property (MB_WEAK) id<MBProgressHUDDelegate> delegate;
```

You need to check the latest MBProgressHUD from Github. It is the same way there on github.

Also if it still gives issues, where in if you are not using ARC then you can use retain instead of MB_WEAK in the above code.

Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

Latest compiler will autosynthesize the properties, ie if you have a property called `delegate` then the synthesized instance variable will be`_delegate`. You are getting the error because `MBProgressHUD.m` file is using `delegate` instead of `_delegate`. To fix this replace the use of `delegate` with `self.delegate` or `_delegate`